# Having problem with subfigures inside multicols environment

Tags: floats, multicol, subcaption, cuted

I am currently working on a document where a figure (with 2 sub-figures) has to be placed inside a 2-column environment like this-
[image: how the document should look like].

I am using `multicols` package for creating the 2-column environment. I am aware of the fact that `multocls` doesn't allow floats inside of it. For this, I found a solution that suggests omitting the `figure` environment, which has been working perfectly fine for me for single figures.

To place the subfigures, I tried `subfigure` environment from `subcaption` package as this-

```tex
\begin{center}
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Picture1a.png}
        \subcaption{}
        \label{fig:one-a}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.45\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/Picture1b.png}
        \subcaption{}
        \label{fig:one-b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \captionof{figure}{Border plant (a) and Durba grass (b)}
    \label{fig:one}
\end{center}
```

Although this shows the subfigures, it does not show the `(a)` and `(b)` under the subfigures.

[image]

And there is an error `Package caption Error: \setcaptionsubtype outside float` on line 2,4,8,10 of the code above. In my experience, the `\subcaption{}` should print the `(a)` and `(b)`.

So the issue here is, `multicols` won't allow floats in it, and `subfigure` throws error when placed outside of float and doesn't show the subcaptions.

Any ideas on how this can be solved?

Comment: Ypou use `subfigure` outside of float `figure` Why? Replace `center` width `figure`.

Comment: As I have mentioned, `multicols` does not allow floats inside it, which is why I omitted the `figure` environment.

Comment: Don't use `multicols`. Use document class option `twocolumn`. And provide MWE. a small but complete document which, reproduce your problem. Environments  `subfigure`/`subtable`  doesn't work outside floats environments.

Comment: BTW, journals using MDPI template dosn't suppose to be used `twocolumn` nor `multicolum` environments.

Comment: A subfigure is just a minipage with captions.  Use `\subcaption{...}` or `\captionof{subfigure}{...}` if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the avoid the problems you found I suggest to use the option `twocolumn` like
`\documentclass[11pt, twoside, twocolumn]{article}`

To make the title page, the abstract and the table in a wide mode use the package `cuted` with `\begin{strip} ... \end{strip}`

The beginning of your document should start as

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{BVetJ}

\usepackage{cuted}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\title{\color{darkBlue}{Wound healing by border plant and green grass (Durba) in Black Bengal goats: A comparative study}}
\author{Sharmistha Bhattacharjee, Moinul Hasan, Md. Shahadot Hossain, Shahinoor Islam, Md. Mahmudul Alam, Mirza Abul Hashim*}
\affil{\small Department of Surgery and Obstetrics, Bangladesh Agricultural University, Mymensingh-2202, Bangladesh}
\date{\vspace{-10ex}}


\begin{document}
%this creates the top content of the first page

\begin{strip} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<
\pagestyle{mypagestyle}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.18\textwidth}
    \raggedleft
        \itshape \bfseries
        \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{images/01_BVA.jpg}\\
        \hfill
         Research Article
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.50\textwidth}
    \centering
        \textbf{Bangladesh Veterinary Journal (2021) 55(1-4): 38-45\\
        pISSN 0378-8113 \textbullet eISSN 2708-6054}\\
        {\footnotesize \url{https://doi.org/10.32856/BVJ-55-2021.04}}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.18\textwidth}
\raggedright
        \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{images/02_blurrLogo.jpg}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.16]{images/03_openAccess.jpg}
\end{minipage}

\begingroup
\let\newpage\relax
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{one}
\endgroup

\hfill\\    
\HRule
\begin{abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Abstract}
    This investigation was done on 12 Black Bengal goats to find out the comparative effects of border plant and green grass (durba) on histo-morphological changes in the cutaneous wounds at Veterinary Teaching Hospital, Bangladesh Agricultural University. Ten experimental cutaneous wounds for each group (n=04) were made in the goats following standard procedure. In Group A 100\% plant extracts of Border plant (\textit{Aerve sanguinolenta}), in Group B Green grass (durba) (\textit{Cynodon dactylon}) and in Group C control 0.85\% normal saline were applied. Clinical investigation revealed that border plant enhances wound healing within 11 days of treatment, which however takes 14 days for durba grass and 18 days for saline treatment. Clinical features revealed reddening was lower in Group A and B following day 5 of treatment compared to a high level of reddening in the wound areas of control skin. The level of cicatrization and pigmentation of wounds was higher in Group A and B until day 12 of treatment. On day 15 of treatment complete healing was seen in wounds treated with Border plant and durba grasses. Microbiological studies show the microorganisms isolated from the wounds were \textit{Staphylococcus spp}, \textit{E. coli} and \textit{Bacillus spp}. On histopathological studies, the highest degree of inflammation and tissue response was seen in Group A goats trailed by Groups B and C goats. Complete keratinization was only seen over the injured skin of Group A goats following 7 days of treatment compared to incomplete keratinization in Group B and lack of keratinization in Group C. The results indicate that Border plant is an effective topical therapeutic agent followed by green grass (durba) extract for treatment of wounds in Black Bengal goats. 
\end{abstract}\vspace*{\baselineskip}

{\small \textbf{Keywords:} Cutaneous wound; Wound healing, Histopathological study}\\
\HRule
\hspace{10mm}
\end{strip} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<


...
```

**Remove all** `\begin{multicols}{2}` and `\end{multicols}` from the rest of the document.

Use this file for `figure1.tex` (two figures side by side in a single column)

```
%% File figure1.tex

\noindent\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
    \centering 
    \includegraphics [width = 0.45\columnwidth, height =0.45\columnwidth]{figures/Picture1a.png}       
    \hfill
    \includegraphics [width = 0.45\columnwidth, height =0.45\columnwidth]{figures/Picture1b.png}\\      
    (a)\hspace{ 0.5\columnwidth}(b)
    \captionof{figure}{Border plant (a) and Durba grass (b)}
    \label{fig:one}
\end{minipage}
```

Use this file for `table1.tex` (a table two columns wide)

```
%%File table 1.tex

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{strip}       
        \centering 
    \captionof{table}{Range of granulation time and complete healing time in different treatment groups of goats}
    \label{tab:one}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.10}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|P{5cm}|P{4cm}|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Groups}     & \textbf{Treatment used}   & \textbf{Range of granulation time (days)}     & \textbf{Complete healing time (days)} \\ \hline
        Group-A             & Border Plant extract      & 3-7       & $11\pm0.39$       \\ \hline
        Group-B             & Durba extract             & 3-9       & $14\pm0.29$       \\ \hline
        Group-C             & Normal saline (0.85\%)    & 5-11      & $18\pm0.42$       \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}   
\end{strip}
```

**Output**

First page

[image: e]

Figures

[image: d]

Table

[image: c]